# Horizontally slide div content and exceed window limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code with two DIVs floating to right:

```
<div class="sample1"></div>
<div class="sample2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.sample1,
.sample2 {
    height: 50vh;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Div "sample1" will get its width bigger by jQuery on a click event. Div "sample2" will break down, because it will exceed the window limit. What I need is to push "sample2" without breaking it down.

Any ideas about how is it possible with CSS only solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
overflow-x:scroll;
```

As described here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp

Comment: Well, didn't know it would be that simple. Thankyou, works for me.

Comment: no problem, would you mind accepting answer pleaser, thanks